# How to compare 2 Either objects in unit test (objects extend Equatable)

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing

I am passing `Either<Failure, List<CleaningJob>>` from the repository. In my unit test, I receive an error that Expected  does not match Actual.

`CleaningJob` extends `Equatable` and both strings, expected and actual, are identical (compared both with Excel...).

I would assume that `Either` (or `Right`) do not have own instances and that therefore I should be able to compare both `Equatable` objects. But it doesn't work for some reason.

And since there is no real message why the test fails, only Expected and Actual are shown, I have no idea how to fix this.

The error looks like this:
`Expected: Right<Failure, List<CleaningJob>>:<Right([CleaningJob(testJobId, ...`

The test statement is
`expect(result, tCleaningJobsModelResponse);`

And I build my expected result with
`final Either<Failure, List<CleaningJob>> tCleaningJobsModelResponse = Right(tCleaningJobsModel);`

Comment: One thing, you are expecting Right to a Either? `Either<Failure, List<CleaningJob>> tCleaningJobsModelResponse = Right(tCleaningJobsModel);`

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly. Also `result` is created with `Right()`. So I am assigning the following function to `result`: `Future<Either<Failure, List<CleaningJob>>> getCleaningJobs({...`. And this function returns `return Right(cleaningJobs);` And in the test result, the value for Actual and for Expected are identical (including `Right<Failure, List<CleaningJob>>:<Right(`